# trouble configuring nginx on ec2 instance for Magento

Tags: magento, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to install Magento 1.9 on a Amazon EC2 server which is running NGINX & HHVM.  I've got HHVM & NGINX running and when I put the EC2 Serers's IP in the URL I get the NGINX welcome screen displayed but when I put in the url to my Magento app (i.e. http://54.???.??.???/dev-magento) I get a 404 error.

I've put Magento in */var/www/dev-magento* rather than */usr/share/nginx/html/*.  I intend to have a *staging-magento* site also which is why I'm not just dropping Magento into */usr/share/nginx/html/*.

I've set up the */etc/www/* directory with

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data * -R
sudo usermod -a -G www-data ubuntu
```

I've also put created an nginx configuration file for the dev-magento site in */etc/nginx/sites-available.dev-magento*

```
server {
    # Listen on port 80 as well as post 443 for SSL connections.
    listen 80;
    #listen 443 default ssl;

    server_name 54.???.??.???/dev-magento;

    # Specify path to your SSL certificates.
   #ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certificates/yourcertificate.crt;
    #ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certificates/yourcertificate.key;

    # Path to the files in which you wish to
    # store your access and error logs.
    #access_log /path/to/your/logs/access_log;
    #error_log /path/to/your/logs/error_log;

    # If the site is accessed via mydomain.com
    # automatically redirect to www.magento.localhost.com.
    #if ($host = 'dev-magento' ) {
        #rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.dev-magento/$1permanent;
   #}

    root /var/www/dev-magento/;

    location / {
        index index.html index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
    }

    # Deny access to specific directories no one
    # in particular needs access to anyways.
    location /app/ { deny all; }
    location /includes/ { deny all; }
    location /lib/ { deny all; }
    location /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
    location /pkginfo/ { deny all; }
    location /report/config.xml { deny all; }
    location /var/ { deny all; }

    # Allow only those who have a login name and password
    # to view the export folder. Refer to /etc/nginx/htpassword.
    #location /var/export/ {
    #    auth_basic "Restricted";
    #    auth_basic_user_file htpasswd;
    #    autoindex on;
    #}

    # Deny all attempts to access hidden files
    # such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, etc...
    location ~ /\. {
         deny all;
         access_log off;
         log_not_found off;
    }

    # This redirect is added so to use Magentos
    # common front handler when handling incoming URLs.
    location @handler {
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }

    # Forward paths such as /js/index.php/x.js
    # to their relevant handler.
    location ~ .php/ {
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }

    # Handle the exectution of .php files.
    location ~ .php$ {
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite / /index.php last;
        }
        expires off;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        #fastcgi_param HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

After which I ran:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/dev-magento /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
sudo service nginx restart
sudo service hhvm restart
```

However I'm still getting a 404 page when I go to 54.???.??.???/dev-magento.

I think I must be missing something pretty obvhious as I'm very new to AWS & NGINX configurations.

Comment: Are the Magento requests being made by IP address, not domain name?  Even so, I'm not sure NGINX supports that hybrid `server_name` you have there.  According to the [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html), it would just be the IP address without the subfolder.

Comment: perhaps I need to edit the _etc/hosts_ file

Comment: I would try removing `/dev-magento` from your `server_name` directive.  If you want to resolve requests like 54.x.y.z/dev-magento, I would add the dev-magento part to your location directive as explained [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).

Comment: @steveklein, I changed it to `server_name   dev-magento;` and added `54.???.??.???         dev-magento` to my local machines _/etc/hosts_ file.  Now I'm getting a 502 Bad gateway when I point the url to http://dev-magento/.  It seems like it's hitting the right location on the server as the magento favicon is in the browser tab.

Comment: Hmm not sure I would recommend changing /etc/hosts.  Did you try what I suggested and it didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by  I changing the server name in my nginx configuration file to `server_name dev-magento;` and then adding `54.???.??.??? dev-magento` to my local machines */etc/hosts* file.